# Manually register AMQP/RabbitMQ message listener to resources.groovy?

Tags: spring, grails, rabbitmq

i seem to keep running into trouble when using the RabbitMQ plugin, so i want to fallback to handling it using Spring RabbitMQ. I am looking for a way on how to register message listeners to my grails application and how to configure that via the resources.groovy.
Any pointers or examples on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good blog entry on using spring and rabbitmq. You will not want to use the cloud tag.

http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20322602-getting-started-with-the-rabbitmq-service-from-a-spring-application

Here is the source repo for spring rabbitmq

https://github.com/momania/spring-rabbitmq

https://github.com/momania/spring-rabbitmq/blob/master/src/test/resources/spring-examples.xml

If you add a  grails-app/conf/spring/resources.xml file you can use xml based spring beans instead of groovy.  May be easier for you.

Also take a look at

[Spring integration with RabbitMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878526/spring-integration-with-rabbitmq)